# How to use SVG clipPath with symbols and <use>

Tags: svg, clip-path

I have the following SVG which works:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="triangle" class="triangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <polygon points="0,100 50,0 100,100" stroke="none" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="rect" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width='100' height='100' stroke="none"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#rect" width="300" height="300" x="100" y="100"/>
  <use xlink:href="#triangle" width="120" height="150" x="180" y="100" fill="white" transform="rotate(180, 250, 175)"/>
</svg>
```

But then when I try to make it into a `clipPath` it goes blank. Wondering how to get `clipPath` to work. Here is what I've tried.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="triangle" class="triangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <polygon points="0,100 50,0 100,100" stroke="none" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="rect" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width='100' height='100' stroke="none"/>
    </symbol>
    
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <use xlink:href="#triangle" width="120" height="150" x="180" y="100" fill="white" transform="rotate(180, 250, 175)"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#rect" width="300" height="300" x="100" y="100" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

The goal is to have it cut out the triangle out of the rectangle, while using the `<use>` functionality. I might have a much more complex clipping path example later on, this just demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Use the polygon inside the symbol not the symbol. [Support `<g>` element in clipping paths](https://github.com/w3c/fxtf-drafts/issues/17): _In addition to <g>, the following elements are disallowed inside of <clipPath> without a clear justification:

<use> elements that reference a `<g>` or another `<use>` (instead of a shape or text element directly)
`<svg>` elements and `<use>` elements that reference `<symbol>`_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the SVG spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#masking-EstablishingANewClippingPath

> A ‘clipPath’ element can contain ‘path’ elements, ‘text’ elements, basic shapes (such as ‘circle’) or a ‘use’ element. If a ‘use’ element is a child of a ‘clipPath’ element, it must directly reference ‘path’, ‘text’ or basic shape elements. **Indirect references are an error**

Comment: Seems kind of dumb that you can't even reuse a `g` of `path`s in a `clipPath`.